# How can I use a type with generic arguments as a constraint?

Tags: c#, generics, constraints

I would like to specify a constraint which is another type with a generic argument.

```
class KeyFrame<T>
{
    public float Time;
    public T Value;
}

// I want any kind of Keyframe to be accepted
class Timeline<T> where T : Keyframe<*>
{
}
```

But this cannot be done in c# as of yet, (and I really doubt it will ever be). Is there any elegant solution to this rather than having to specify the type of the keyframe argument?:

```
class Timeline<TKeyframe, TKeyframeValue> 
     where TKeyframe : Keyframe<TKeyframeValue>,
{
}
```

Comment: What version of C# are you using... never see Timeline<T> where T : Keyframe<*> of my life

Comment: Timeline is a class of my own :)

Comment: I think the desire would be to have similar to 'template-template classes' from C++, so
class Timeline<Keyframe<T> >
{

}

to enforce the use of any specialisation of Keyframe as a constraint of Timeline

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read about this from [Eric Lippert's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2008/05/19/a-generic-constraint-question.aspx)
Basically, you have to find a way to refer to the type you want without specifying the secondary type parameter.

In his post, he shows this example as a possible solution:

```
public abstract class FooBase
{
  private FooBase() {} // Not inheritable by anyone else
  public class Foo<U> : FooBase {...generic stuff ...}

  ... nongeneric stuff ...
}

public class Bar<T> where T: FooBase { ... }
...
new Bar<FooBase.Foo<string>>()
```

Hope that helps, 
Troy

Comment: Thanks for the reading. I think the FooBase approach is quite elegant and never thought of it. :)

Answer (score 2):

As TimeLine is most likely an aggregation of KeyFrames, wouldn't something like:

```
class TimeLine<T>
{
private IList<KeyFrame<T>> keyFrameList;
...
}
```

fulfill your requirements nicely?

Comment: Wouldn't you at least do an IList (or similar interface) to not hamstring the consumer too much.

Comment: Was just doing some throwaway code and C# isn't my most familiar language. Chances are that an IList would be better :)

Comment: Yes, that was exactly my first implementation but it did not fulfill my requirements as you said. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If the type T that `Timeline<T>` represents is the same as the type `KeyFrame<T>` represents you can just go with:

```
class Timeline<T>
{
  List<KeyFrame<T>> _frames = new List<KeyFrame<T>>(); //Or whatever...

  ...
}
```

If type T represents something different between the classes that implies that `Timeline<T>` can contain multiple types of `KeyFrame`'s in which case you should create a more abstract implementation of `KeyFrame` and use that in `Timeline<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe nesting `Timeline` inside `KeyFrame` would make sense in your design:

```
class KeyFrame<T> { 
  public float Time; 
  public T Value; 

  class Timeline<U> where U : Keyframe<T> { 
  } 
}
```